# Configuring Octave for Dynare on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, octave

I am trying to configure my GNU Octave 6.2.0 (https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) for Dynare 4.6.4 (https://www.dynare.org), but I am running in circles for hours.

I am following all the steps proposed for macOS in the Dynare webpage:
https://www.dynare.org/resources/quick_start/#configuring-octave-for-dynare-on-windows.

When I get to the **Configuring Octave for Dynare on macOS** part, my Octave Command Window shows:

```
>> addpath /Users/fabioazevedo/Desktop/Fabio/Dynare for Economics/Dynare/4.6.4/matlab
warning: addpath: Economics/Dynare/4.6.4/matlab: No such file or directory
warning: addpath: for: No such file or directory
warning: addpath: /Users/fabioazevedo/Desktop/Fabio/Dynare: No such file or directory
```

Which is quite wrong because I do have this file folder path...

Could you please help me configure Octave for Dynare?

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

When using `addpath` without quotes, the path must not contain spaces. Otherwise, Matlab thinks you are trying to add a list of space-separated paths.